# cakephp 2, edit record in modal by bootstrap

Tags: cakephp, modal-dialog

How to edit a record with Cakephp and modal bootstrap?

Because when I edit a contact, I get the error 500?

> missing view The view for UserContactsController:: admin_modal_edit()
>   was not found.

In to controller admin_modal_edit() I have set $this->layout = NULL;

These are the files of the app.

File: user/view.ctp with list of contact and the modal for add or edit.

BUTTON FOR EDIT OR DELETE

```html
<?php echo $userContact['UserContactType']['title']; ?>: <?php echo $userContact['contact']; ?>

<a href="<?php echo $this->Html->url(array('controller' => 'user_contacts', 'action' => 'modal_edit', $userContact['id'] )); ?>" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><?php echo __('Edit'); ?></a>
```

BOOTSTRAP MODAL

```html
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('UserContact', array('url' => array('admin' => true, 'prefix' => 'admin', 'plugin' => 'user', 'controller' => 'user_contacts', 'action' => 'modal_edit')));
?>

<?php echo $this->Form->input('UserContact.id', array('class' => 'form-control')); ?>

<?php echo $this->Form->input('UserContact.user_id', array('default' => $user_id, 'type' => 'hidden')); ?>

<?php echo $this->Form->input('UserContact.user_contact_type_id', array('class' => 'form-control', 'empty' => true)); ?>

<?php echo $this->Form->input('UserContact.contact', array('class' => 'form-control')); ?>

<?php echo $this->Form->submit(__('Save'), array('div' => false, 'class' => 'btn btn-success')); ?>

<?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

File: controller/UsersController.php that generates view.ctp

```
public function admin_view($id = null) {
    if (!$this->User->exists($id)) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid user'));
    }
    $user_id = $id;
    $options = array(
        'contain' => array('UserContact' => 'UserContactType', 'UserGroup', 'UserState', 'UserGender', 'UserAddress' => 'UserAddressType', 'UserPaymentType', 'Item', 'Comment'),
        'conditions' => array('User.' . $this->User->primaryKey => $id));
    $this->set('user', $this->User->find('first', $options));

    // blocco find list
    $userContactTypes = $this->UserContactType->find('list');
    $userAddressTypes = $this->UserAddressType->find('list');
$this->set(compact(array('userContactTypes', 'userAddressTypes', 'user_id')));
}
```

File: controller/UserContactsController.php for the modal

```
public function admin_modal_edit() {
    $id =  $this->request->query('id');
    $this->layout = NULL;
    if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {

        if ($this->UserContact->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The record has been saved'), 'flash/success');
            $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'view', $this->request->data['UserContact']['user_id']));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The record could not be saved. Please, try again.'), 'flash/error');
        }
    } else {
        if (!empty($id)) {
            $options = array('conditions' => array("UserContact.{$this->UserContact->primaryKey}" => $id));
            $this->request->data = $this->UserContact->find('first', $options);

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What are you expecting `admin_modal_edit()` to do? Have you created the admin_modal_edit.ctp View template? At the moment your code is attempting to render that View which presumably hasn't been created.

Comment: admin_modal_edit() it must save the contacts with insert or edit. I did not create the view admin_modal_edit.ctp, because it is a modal window. Inserting it can do, but does not work when edit an old record.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that CakePHP is trying to render the 'admin_modal_edit.ctp' View template.

If you don't want CakePHP to render anything set [`autoRender` to `false`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller::render):-

```
public function admin_modal_edit() {
    $this->autoRender = false;
}
```

This will prevent CakePHP from looking for a View template to render.

`$this->layout = null` does not stop Cake from attempting to render templates. Which I suspect is what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

This error is showing because `cakephp` is complaining about the function `admin_modal_edit` for not having a view since it cannot find the `admin_modal_edit.ctp` in the view folder of your controller.

To fix this, add this

> `$this->autoRender = false`

to your function `admin_modal_edit` to disable the rendering of view for that function.

So your function should look like this.

```
public function admin_modal_edit() {
    /** --------------   **/
    $this->autoRender = false;
    /** --------------  **/

    $id =  $this->request->query('id');
    if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
        if ($this->UserContact->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The record has been saved'), 'flash/success');
            $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'view', $this->request->data['UserContact']['user_id']));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The record could not be saved. Please, try again.'), 'flash/error');
        }
    } else {
        if (!empty($id)) {
            $options = array('conditions' => array("UserContact.{$this->UserContact->primaryKey}" => $id));
            $this->request->data = $this->UserContact->find('first', $options);
        }
   }
}
```